# Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O

Tags: android

I am building a weather forecast app using API from this(openweathermap.org) website. For this I have used two dependencies such as 
1."com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0" and 
2."com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

And I got this error message that I have given below:

[CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.android.tools.r8.a: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)]

Now how can I solve this error

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by adding the compileOptionsion {...} in android block of your app build.gradle.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {...}
  buildTypes {...}

  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```